# Getting metabox value within a shortcode?

Tags: metabox, shortcode

Is it possible to get page's metabox value within shortcode that is executed on that page?

Scenario:

- I have a sidebar metabox for every page.
- I have some kind of custom
  gallery shortcode.

My gallery shortcode outputs 600x200 images (I'm using timthumb here).

BUT I want it to display 900x300 if there's no sidebar.

Normally I'd use:

```
$sidebar = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'metabox_sidebar', true);
   if($sidebar == "true") { do something }
   else { do something else }
```

But get_post_meta returns nothing within the shortcode body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$post` is outside the scope of your shortcode function, you have to globalize it first:

```
global $post;
$sidebar = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'metabox_sidebar', true);
```

Comment: Oh, my, God :) It's always like this, I'm working on complex things and everything works better than expected then something like this happens and I'm stuck. Thanks a lot, sorry for another super-lame question.